# Flatten or unpack list of nested dicts in DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

Snippet from TMDB csv file:

```
movie_id,title,cast,crew
19995,Avatar,"[{""cast_id"": 242, ""character"": ""Jake Sully"", ""credit_id"": ""5602a8a7c3a3685532001c9a"", ""gender"": 2, ""id"": 65731, ""name"": ""Sam Worthington"", ""order"": 0}, {""cast_id"": 3, ""character"": ""Neytiri"", ""credit_id"": ""52fe48009251416c750ac9cb"", ""gender"": 1, ""id"": 8691, ""name"": ""Zoe Saldana"", ""order"": 1}, {""cast_id"": 25, ""character"": ""Dr. Grace Augustine"", ""credit_id"": ""52fe48009251416c750aca39"", ""gender"": 1, ""id"": 10205, ""name"": ""Sigourney Weaver"", ""order"": 2}, {""cast_id"": 4, ""character"": ""Col. Quaritch"", ""credit_id"": ""52fe48009251416c750ac9cf"", ""gender"": 2, ""id"": 32747, ""name"": ""Stephen Lang"", ""order"": 3}, {""cast_id"": 5, ""character"": ""Trudy Chacon"", ""credit_id"": ""52fe48009251416c750ac9d3"", ""gender"": 1, ""id"": 17647, ""name"": ""Michelle Rodriguez"", ""order"": 4}, {""cast_id"": 8, ""character"": ""Selfridge"", ""credit_id"": ""52fe48009251416c750ac9e1"", ""gender"": 2, ""id"": 1771, ""name"": ""Giovanni Ribisi"", ""order"": 5}
```

Code:

```
tmdb_credit_df = pd.read_csv('tmdb.csv')
tmdb_credit_df['cast'] = tmdb_credit_df['cast'].apply(eval)
```

The each cell in `cast` column contain a list of dicts. Example:

```
[{'cast_id': 242,
  'character': 'Jake Sully',
  'credit_id': '5602a8a7c3a3685532001c9a',
  'gender': 2,
  'id': 65731,
  'name': 'Sam Worthington',
  'order': 0},
 {'cast_id': 3,
  'character': 'Neytiri',
  'credit_id': '52fe48009251416c750ac9cb',
  'gender': 1,
  'id': 8691,
  'name': 'Zoe Saldana',
  'order': 1}, ...]
```

I'm trying to flatten the dataframe so that it looks like:

```
    movie_id    title   cast_id    character    ...
0   19995      Avatar   242        Jake Sully   ...
1   19995      Avatar   3          Neytiri      ...
```

Is there a way to use `json_normalize()` or maybe `.apply()` to flatten/unpack this table as opposed to looping through every row?

I tried to use `json_normalize(tmdb_credit_df.cast)`, but I got an error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I also tried `tmdb_credit_df.cast.apply(lambda x: x[0])` to extract one field at a time, but I got the following error:

`list index out of range`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with -

```
df

   movie_id   title                                               cast
0     19995  Avatar  [{"cast_id": 242, "character": "Jake Sully", "...
```

Here, `cast` is a column of *strings*.

1. First, convert the `cast` column to a column of python objects, by using `json.loads`
2. Next, convert `df` to a dict using `to_dict`
3. Finally, call `json_normalize` with the appropriate params -

First two steps are shown below, using `apply(pd.io.json.loads)` + `to_dict` -

```
d = df.assign(cast=df.cast.apply(pd.io.json.loads)).to_dict('r')
```

Next, call `json_normalize` with the `meta` and `record_path` arguments  -

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, meta=['movie_id', 'title'], record_path=['cast'])
df

   cast_id            character                 credit_id  gender     id  \
0      242           Jake Sully  5602a8a7c3a3685532001c9a       2  65731   
1        3              Neytiri  52fe48009251416c750ac9cb       1   8691   
2       25  Dr. Grace Augustine  52fe48009251416c750aca39       1  10205   
3        4        Col. Quaritch  52fe48009251416c750ac9cf       2  32747   
4        5         Trudy Chacon  52fe48009251416c750ac9d3       1  17647   
5        8            Selfridge  52fe48009251416c750ac9e1       2   1771   

                 name  order   title  movie_id  
0     Sam Worthington      0  Avatar     19995  
1         Zoe Saldana      1  Avatar     19995  
2    Sigourney Weaver      2  Avatar     19995  
3        Stephen Lang      3  Avatar     19995  
4  Michelle Rodriguez      4  Avatar     19995  
5     Giovanni Ribisi      5  Avatar     19995
```

Comment: How would this be modified if I had more than one column that needed to be flattened? For example if there was a `crew` column that was similar to `cast`? I got `d = df.assign(cast=df.cast.apply(pd.io.json.loads),crew=df.crew.apply(pd.io.json.loads)).to_dict('r') ` to work; but I had issues normalizing with `df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, meta=['movie_id', 'title'], record_path=['cast','crew'])`

Comment: @user1964692 Hmm, that should have worked... but will need more context. If possible, would appreciate if you could open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This loops over the csv and converts the json (`cast_str`) to a Python list of dicts (`cast`), passes that into Pandas' DataFrame constructor (`cast_df`), appends the resulting DataFrame to a list (`frames`), and then finally combines the contents of `frames` into one big DataFrame (`df`).

```py
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd

path = "/path/to/file/tmdb.csv"
frames = list()

reader = csv.reader(open(path))
next(reader)  # skip the header row in csv

for movie_id_str, title, cast_str, _ in reader:

    cast = json.loads(cast_str)            
    cast_df = pd.DataFrame(cast)            
    cast_df['movie_id'] = int(movie_id)
    cast_df['title'] = title
    frames.append(cast_df)

df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
```

Note, I did need to change your test data by adding `]", "[]"` to the end in order for it to parse correctly.